# how to show info text on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show info popup in android which need to get closed only when list count is greater than zero (user cannot close the box), it should be placed absolute on top of activity window

Attached screenshot of some ipad app showing popup
[image: Attached screenshot of some ipad app showing popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refere this links to get some idea about what you are looking....

http://www.ceveni.com/2009/09/popup-window-in-android-sample-program.html

http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Will a float window be able to accomplish this?

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/404cfbecbf4fd403